# Save contents of a QTableWidget to a MySQL database

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

In the .NET world, if I wanted to save the contents of a DataTable, I would use:

```cs
MySqlCommandBuilder cmb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter); //adapter -> MySqlDataAdapter
adapter.Update(ds, "item"); //ds -> DataSet
```

```vb
Dim cmb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter) 'adapter -> MySqlDataAdapter
adapter.Update(ds, "item") 'ds -> DataSet
```

How do I achieve similar functionality where I am able to save contents of a QTableWidget into a MySQL table in Qt for C++? I had initially thought of iterating through the QTableWidget but it does not look feasible...

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i) {
    //Iterating headers
    header = table->horizontalHeaderItem(i)->data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();       
}

for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j) {
        //Iterating cells
        cell = table->model()->data(table->model()->index(i, j)).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check out [QSqlTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqltablemodel.html)?

Comment: @king_nak Yes but it accesses data from the database. I'm interested in writing to the database instead.

Comment: @king_nak What does [this code](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqltablemodel.html#details) do?

Comment: That populates a model with data from a table, but you can leave out the select() step to skip reading from the database. With the manual edit strategy you should then call submitAll() to attempt writing the current model data.

Comment: @sigma Will this work when I use multiple `QTableView` each with their models and `left join` queries?

Comment: Possibly...The QSqlTableModel needs a database to be able to work, but I found [this file](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/sql/connection.h?h=6.3) in their example code where they create one in memory. So maybe you can prepare your tables like that and create a table model for each.